# RFID Locking user memory

Tags: c#, rfid, octane-sdk

I am working on the RFID tags.I am using Speedway Revolution Reader(R-420) for reading the tags.
http://www.impinj.com/Speedway_Revolution_UHF_RFID_Reader.aspx
I am using Confidex Steelware Micro ETSI Monza tags (Product No. 3000127)
http://www.confidex.com/products-and-services/compare-uhf-products/524-confidex-steelwave-micro. I am using Impinj's Octane SDK.
I am facing the problem that when I am trying to Lock User memory,I am getting error.

This is the code I am using:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to the reader.
            // Change the ReaderHostname constant in SolutionConstants.cs 
            // to the IP address or hostname of your reader.
            reader.Connect(SolutionConstants.ReaderHostname);

            // Assign the TagOpComplete event handler.
            // This specifies which method to call
            // when tag operations are complete.
            reader.TagOpComplete += OnTagOpComplete;

            // Configure the reader with the default settings.
            reader.ApplyDefaultSettings();

            // Create a tag operation sequence.
            // You can add multiple read, write, lock, kill and QT
            // operations to this sequence.
            TagOpSequence seq = new TagOpSequence();


            // Define a tag write operation that sets the access password. 
            TagWriteOp writeOp = new TagWriteOp();
            // Assumes that current access password is not set
            // (zero is the default)
            writeOp.AccessPassword = null;
            // The access password is in the Reserved memory bank.
            writeOp.MemoryBank = MemoryBank.Reserved;
            // A pointer to the start of the access password.
            writeOp.WordPointer = WordPointers.AccessPassword;
            // The new access password to write.
            writeOp.Data = TagData.FromHexString("11112222");

            // Add this tag write op to the tag operation sequence.
            seq.Ops.Add(writeOp);

            // Create a tag lock operation to lock the 
            // access password and User memory.
            TagLockOp lockOp = new TagLockOp();
            lockOp.AccessPasswordLockType = TagLockState.Lock;
            lockOp.EpcLockType = TagLockState.Lock;


            // Add this tag lock op to the tag operation sequence.
            seq.Ops.Add(lockOp);

            // Add the tag operation sequence to the reader.
            // The reader supports multiple sequences.
            reader.AddOpSequence(seq);

            // Start the reader
            reader.Start();
        }
        catch (OctaneSdkException e)
        {
            // Handle Octane SDK errors.
            Console.WriteLine("Octane SDK exception: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle other .NET errors.
            Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", e.Message);
        }

        // Wait for the user to press enter.
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Stop reading.
        reader.Stop();

        // Disconnect from the reader.
        reader.Disconnect();
    }

    // This event handler will be called when tag 
    // operations have been executed by the reader.
    static void OnTagOpComplete(ImpinjReader reader, TagOpReport report)
    {
        // Loop through all the completed tag operations
        foreach (TagOpResult result in report)
        {
            if (result is TagWriteOpResult)
            {
                // These are the results of settings the access password.
                // Cast it to the correct type.
                TagWriteOpResult writeResult = result as TagWriteOpResult;
                // Print out the results.
                Console.WriteLine("Set access password complete.");
                Console.WriteLine("EPC : {0}", writeResult.Tag.Epc);
                Console.WriteLine("Status : {0}", writeResult.Result);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of words written : {0}", writeResult.NumWordsWritten);
            }
            else if (result is TagLockOpResult)
            {
                // Cast it to the correct type.
                // These are the results of locking the access password or user memory.
                TagLockOpResult lockResult = result as TagLockOpResult;
                // Print out the results.
                Console.WriteLine("Lock operation complete.");
                Console.WriteLine("EPC : {0}", lockResult.Tag.Epc);
                Console.WriteLine("Status : {0}", lockResult.Result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the error I am getting : "No response from Tag"

Comment: did you try to communicate with RFID via simple ASCII commands ?

Comment: No, I have not tried.Can you share any link for ASCII commands?

Comment: Not very sure if there is a common command set among different manufacturers (just don't know). You *should* have some documentation provided among RFID tag itself. Years ago I did this (I had a documentation of a communiccation protocol provided by manufacturer itself), but I don't know if it's a different in your case-

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this guide? http://learn.impinj.com/articles/en_US/RFID/Locking-Memory-on-EPC-RFID-Tags/

Comment: Yes, I am following that code even then I am getting STATUS as No Response from Tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the steps in the guide mentioned above, there is no reason why it shouldn't be working UNLESS the tag is already locked.

Because locked status often cannot be read by the reader but only inferred, it may be in this case the tag (or tags) you are using are for some reason already locked. I recommend trying a few different types of tags (with different ICs if possible) to see if the error persists across the board.